# How do I repeat the number of times in a PHP loop?

Tags: php

There is an array of any with the keys permissible from 1 to 10.

There is a cycle from 1 to the current day (let's say the number today is 7 every day corresponds to a new day).

How to make it so that in the cycle from one to today we receive the body of the array by the key?

From 1 to 10 it is understandable, but how to repeat the array keys in a loop. Suppose there will be a thirtieth day, it should show the body of the array with key 10.

```
        public function getRation($getration)
{
    //ration - it's day
    $ration = RationDay::all()->toArray();
    $count = count($ration);
    $s=1;
    for ($i=0; $i<$getration; $i++)
    {
        $kekes = $s++;
        if($s<=$count){
         if($kekes>=$count){
             $kekes = 1;
         }else{
        if(isset($ration[$kekes])){
                $s=1;
        }else{
            $kek = $ration[$kekes];
        }
        }
    }
```

This is one of several solutions.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. The day goes separately from the array, the day I get from angularjs through request. If the day is larger than the array, then it should repeat the output of the keys is valid. Example: Day 13 - Key = 3.

I for example tried to do it all through for, but something is not successful.

Upd. There was an interesting idea, to receive the remainder of the division. But the remainder of the division will not work, because if there is an array with keys from 1 to 6. Then let's say it does not work out that 9 day is the key 3.

UPD 2. Here's the solution if anyone should. Thank you all for the response!

```
//get array
$ration = RationDay::all()->toArray();

$count = count($ration);
//getration - it day
$day = $getration;

if ($day >= ($maxDay = max(array_keys($ration)))) {
    $day = $day % $maxDay;
}

$getting = $ration[$day];

return $getting;
```

Comment: What have you already tried (show us code)? hat is your desired output? What is your input?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution if anyone should. Thank you all for the response!

```
    //get array
    $ration = RationDay::all()->toArray();

    $count = count($ration);
    //getration - it day
    $day = $getration;

    if ($day >= ($maxDay = max(array_keys($ration)))) {
        $day = $day % $maxDay;
    }

    $getting = $ration[$day];

    return $getting;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would have the best luck if you had your counter have a base 10.

```
$count = 0
for ($day = 1; $day <= $limit; $day++) {
   if ($count = 10) {
      $count = 0;
   }
   $count++;
   echo $array[$count];
}
```

Comment: `$ration = RationDay::all()->toArray();

  $count = count($ration);

  $kek=1;

 for ($day = 1; $day <= $getration; $day++) {
  if ($kek = $count) {
   $kek = 1;
  }
  $kek++;
  $getting = $ration[$kek];
}
  return $getting;
`
Does not work

Comment: Arrays start at index 0 by default, I assumed that you were creating an array manually that started at index 1. 

try
$ration = RationDay::all()->toArray(); 
$count = count($ration); 
$kek=0; 
for ($day = 1; $day <= $getration; $day++) { 
if ($kek == ($count - 1)) { $kek = 0; 
} else { 
$kek++; 
}
$getting = $ration[$kek]; 
} 
return $getting;